# Team not appearing while creating workflow in Xcode Cloud

Tags: xcode, workflow, xcode-cloud

I am creating Xcode cloud workflow for my client's team but it is showing only my personal account team.

I have added development certificate and provisioning profile from client's account successfully. And my client's team is appearing in "Signing & capabilities" tab.

Please guide why it is not showing up while creating workflow.

[image: My client's team not appearing]